# Folder structure, where to store forms

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I'm using ZendStudio which creates an MVC structure for projects.

To create a form, I just create a PHP class and extend Zend_Form, but where is the right location to have this form saved.

I've seen someone put it in

```
application/forms
```

with

```
application/models
application/views
application/controllers
```

Is this a best practice or is there a more logical location than this? What do you do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`application/forms` is what Zend Reference Guide [recommends](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/project-structure.project.html)